# Computing vowel frequency with R

Tags: r, string, frequency

Can you please give me a hint on what's the best and easiest way to compute the absolute and relative frequencies of vowels in a string using R?

I guess the source code is a bit different from what I've found so far in the forum concerning Java.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint as to what your data looks like and what you have tried already?

Comment: Hello Andrie,
not that much, cause I am very new to R and have no experience with programming.

We have like a sentence 

We first elicited the number of letters using the substring function:

letters=substring(s, seq(1,nchar(s),1), seq(1,nchar(s),1))
 and now we working on a for-each loop to extract the frequency of each vowel in a string
something like: 
for int i = 0; i < freq; i++ )
{
  if (x[[1]]=='a'||=='A')
   a++;  But since we both do not have experience with programming we are stuck here..

Comment: { if (x[[i]]=='a'||=='A') a++;..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set up some data:

```
text <- "Can you please give me a hint on what's the best and easiest way to compute the absolute and relative frequencies of vowels in a string using R?

I guess the source code is a bit different from what I've found so far in the forum concerning Java.

Any help is appreciated."
```

Analyse it:

```
x <- tolower(strsplit(text, "")[[1]])
x <- x[x %in% letters]
```

Absolute frequency:

```
table(x)
x
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  y 
19  3  8  6 29  8  5  8 17  1  5  4 16 14  5  1 11 16 17  9  5  4  3
```

Relative frequency:

```
table(x)/length(x)
x
          a           b           c           d           e           f           g           h           i 
0.088785047 0.014018692 0.037383178 0.028037383 0.135514019 0.037383178 0.023364486 0.037383178 0.079439252 
          j           l           m           n           o           p           q           r           s 
0.004672897 0.023364486 0.018691589 0.074766355 0.065420561 0.023364486 0.004672897 0.051401869 0.074766355 
          t           u           v           w           y 
0.079439252 0.042056075 0.023364486 0.018691589 0.014018692
```